# Sip client on Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, sip

We need to develop an application on three mobile `platforms`(`iOS`, `Android`, `WinPhone`), one of the feature of this application will be possibility to make sip calls(`voip`). 
Is it possible to develop such application on `C#` using `Xamarin Studio`? Sip methods should be written on `C#, not ObjC,Java,C++`,etc. Has anyone positive or negative experience with same project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its certainly possible to build a VOIP application using MonoTouch.

Since you are targeting cross platform apps, I suggest you try out [MvvmCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross). Its a fantastic framework for cross platform apps which reduces much of the overhead and lets you focus on your app.

Comment: Can you please provide more arguments for this, maybe a link on existing project?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with xamarin, you would create four projects in a workspace. One for iOS, Android, WinPhone and a Common project.
You would then produce all the common code/logic in the common project and then when required to make an platform specific calls then you would drop down to the platform project.